# Stuck on a simple equality proof

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I'm trying to implement some matrix operations and proofs around them in Agda.
The code involve the something near the following definitions:

```
open import Algebra     
open import Data.Nat hiding (_+_ ; _*_)
open import Data.Vec
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

module Teste {l l'}(cr : CommutativeSemiring l l') where

   open CommutativeSemiring cr hiding (refl)

   _×_ : ℕ → ℕ → Set l
   n × m = Vec (Vec Carrier m) n

   null : {n m : ℕ} → n × m
   null = replicate (replicate 0#)

   infixl 7 _∔_

   _∔_ : {n m : ℕ} → n × m → n × m → n × m
   [] ∔ [] = []
   (xs ∷ xss) ∔ (ys ∷ yss) = zipWith _+_ xs ys ∷ xss ∔ yss
```

I defined a data type for matrices using vectors and define `null` matrix and
the matrix addition. My desire is to prove that `null` is the left identity of
matrix addition:

```
 null-left-id-∔ : ∀ {n m : ℕ} → (xss : n × m) → (null {n} {m}) ∔ xss ≡ xss
```

I've tried to define it by induction on matrix indices, as follows:

```
 null-left-id-∔ : ∀ {n m : ℕ} → (xss : n × m) → (null {n} {m}) ∔ xss ≡ xss
 null-left-id-∔ {zero} {zero} [] = refl
 null-left-id-∔ {zero} {suc m} xss = {!!}
 null-left-id-∔ {suc n} {zero} xss = {!!}
 null-left-id-∔ {suc n} {suc m} xss = {!!}
```

but, in all holes, the function `null` isn't expanded. Since `null` is defined using `replicate` and it uses recursion on natural numbers, I was expecting that
matching on matrix indices would trigger reduction on `null` definition.

Just to mention, I've also tried to define such proof by induction over matrix structure (by recursion on `xss`). Again, the `null` definition isn't expanded in holes.

Am I doing something silly ?

**EDIT**: I'm using Agda 2.5.1.1 and standard library version 0.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're inspecting holes with `C-c C-,` and `C-c C-.` which don't perform full normalization. Try `C-u C-u C-c C-,` and `C-u C-u C-c C-.` instead.

Induction on `xss` almost works:

```
zipWith-+-replicate-0# : ∀ {n} → (xs : Vec Carrier n) → zipWith _+_ (replicate 0#) xs ≡ xs
zipWith-+-replicate-0#  []      = refl
zipWith-+-replicate-0# (x ∷ xs) = cong₂ _∷_ {!!} (zipWith-+-replicate-0# xs)

null-left-id-∔ : ∀ {n m} → (xss : n × m) → null ∔ xss ≡ xss
null-left-id-∔  []        = refl
null-left-id-∔ (xs ∷ xss) = cong₂ _∷_ (zipWith-+-replicate-0# xs) (null-left-id-∔ xss)
```

But your equality is `_≈_` — not `_≡_`, so you can't prove `0# + x ≡ x`. You should use equality from the `Data.Vec.Equality` module, but this is way more verbose:

```
open Equality
    (record { Carrier = Carrier
            ; _≈_ = _≈_
            ; isEquivalence = isEquivalence
            })
  renaming (_≈_ to _≈ᵥ_)

zipWith-+-replicate-0# : ∀ {n} → (xs : Vec Carrier n) → zipWith _+_ (replicate 0#) xs ≈ᵥ xs
zipWith-+-replicate-0#  []      = []-cong
zipWith-+-replicate-0# (x ∷ xs) = IsCommutativeMonoid.identityˡ +-isCommutativeMonoid _
                           ∷-cong zipWith-+-replicate-0# xs

private open module Dummy {m} = Equality
            (record { Carrier = Vec Carrier m
                    ; _≈_ = λ xs ys -> xs ≈ᵥ ys
                    ; isEquivalence = record
                        { refl  = refl _
                        ; sym   = Equality.sym _
                        ; trans = Equality.trans _
                        }
                    })
          renaming (_≈_ to _≈ᵥᵥ_)

null-left-id-∔ : ∀ {n m} → (xss : n × m) → null ∔ xss ≈ᵥᵥ xss
null-left-id-∔  []        = Equality.[]-cong
null-left-id-∔ (xs ∷ xss) = zipWith-+-replicate-0# xs Equality.∷-cong null-left-id-∔ xss
```

[A full snippet](http://lpaste.net/183341).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I always got puzzled by Agda's record / module system.