# Is there a more convenient way to use nested records?

Tags: record, agda

As I told [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302216/stuck-on-a-simple-equality-proof), I'm working in a library about algebra, matrices and category theory. I have decomposed the algebraic structures in a "tower" of record types, each one representing an algebraic structure. As example, to specify a monoid, we define first a semigroup and to define a commutative monoid we use monoid definition, following the same pattern as Agda standard library.

My trouble is that when I need a property of an algebraic structure that is deep within another one (e.g. property of a `Monoid` that is part of a `CommutativeSemiring`) we need to use a number of a projections equal to desired algebraic structure depth.

As an example of my problem, consider the following "lemma":

```
open import Algebra
open import Algebra.Structures
open import Data.Vec
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Algebra.FunctionProperties
open import Data.Product

module _ {Carrier : Set} {_+_ _*_ : Op₂ Carrier} {0# 1# : Carrier} (ICSR : IsCommutativeSemiring _≡_ _+_ _*_ 0# 1#) where

csr : CommutativeSemiring _ _
csr = record{ isCommutativeSemiring = ICSR }

zipWith-replicate-0# : ∀ {n}(xs : Vec Carrier n) → zipWith _+_ (replicate 0#) xs ≡ xs
zipWith-replicate-0# [] = refl
zipWith-replicate-0# (x ∷ xs) = cong₂ _∷_ (proj₁ (IsMonoid.identity (IsCommutativeMonoid.isMonoid
                                                           (IsCommutativeSemiring.+-isCommutativeMonoid
                                                           (CommutativeSemiring.isCommutativeSemiring csr)))) x)
                                          (zipWith-replicate-0# xs)
```

Note that in order to access the left identity property of a monoid, I need to project it from the monoid that is within the commutative monoid that lies in the structure of an commutative semiring.

My concern is that, as I add more and more algebraic structures, such lemmas it will become unreadable.

My question is: Is there a pattern or trick that can avoid this "ladder" of record projections?

Any clue on this is highly welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the Agda standard library, you'll see that for most specialized algebraic structures, the `record` defining them has the less specialized structure `open public`. E.g. in [`Algebra.AbelianGroup`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Algebra.html#2533), we have:

```
record AbelianGroup c ℓ : Set (suc (c ⊔ ℓ)) where
  -- ...  snip ...

  open IsAbelianGroup isAbelianGroup public

  group : Group _ _
  group = record { isGroup = isGroup }

  open Group group public using (setoid; semigroup; monoid; rawMonoid)

  -- ... snip ...
```

So an `AbelianGroup` record will have not just the `AbelianGroup`/`IsAbelianGroup` fields available, but also `setoid`, `semigroup` and `monoid` and `rawMonoid` from `Group`. In turn, `setoid`, `monoid` and `rawMonoid` in `Group` come from similarly `open public`-reexporting these fields from `Monoid`.

Similarly, for algebraic property witnesses, they re-export the less specialized version's fields, e.g. in [`IsAbelianGroup`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Algebra.Structures.html#2245) we have

```
record IsAbelianGroup
         {a ℓ} {A : Set a} (≈ : Rel A ℓ)
         (∙ : Op₂ A) (ε : A) (⁻¹ : Op₁ A) : Set (a ⊔ ℓ) where
  -- ... snip ...
  open IsGroup isGroup public
  -- ... snip ...
```

and then `IsGroup` reexports `IsMonoid`, `IsMonoid` reexports `IsSemigroup`, and so on. And so, if you have `IsAbelianGroup` open, you can still use `assoc` (coming from `IsSemigroup`) without having to write out the whole path to it by hand.

The bottom line is you can write your function as follows:

```
open CommutativeSemiring CSR hiding (refl)
open import Function using (_⟨_⟩_)

zipWith-replicate-0# : ∀ {n}(xs : Vec Carrier n) → zipWith _+_ (replicate 0#) xs ≡ xs
zipWith-replicate-0# [] = refl
zipWith-replicate-0# (x ∷ xs) = proj₁ +-identity x ⟨ cong₂ _∷_ ⟩ zipWith-replicate-0# xs
```